# Has Jessica ever 'claimed' someone?

Tags: true-blood

It's been a while since I've seen True Blood, but from what I remember it's common for vampires to 'stake a claim' on a particular human- Bill, for example did this to keep other vampires from harming Sookie- has Jessica ever claimed a human as 'hers' for any reason?

Answer (score 1):

she has said she claims Jason a few times back in season 5 episode 1 but in other times you will have to rewatch it

Comment: Can you be specific about at least one time?  At least identify the episode, but a quote would be even better.

Comment: season 5 ep 1 she literally says "jason is mine"